# Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Trying to install eclipse

[image]

and I get an error

```
Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.
```

Java -version from command line says

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)
```

How can I change that to a compatible version?  I did google this and cruise this site for answers with the suggested questions when writing this but was not able to find something that solved it.  I found a few answers telling you to do this (with my current installed version in)

```
 export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.*'
```

When I run the EXPORT command it just takes me to a command line and from there I have no idea what to do.

I did download the 64-bit version.

Seems like it should be an easy thing to do....

Comment: which eclipse you are trying to install ,share more details

Comment: updated it with what I clicked on on the site.

Comment: Just installing the 1.8 JDK (must be JDK not the JRE) is enough to make Eclipse work for me.

Comment: I would agree with greg. I found that links directed you to the JRE when in fact you wanted the JDK and it worked immediately after getting the JDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click `Eclipse` and click `Show Package Contents`

[image]

And open `Contents\info.plist` in a texteditor

[image]

Then search for `<key>Eclipse</key>` and immediately after the `<key>Eclipse</key>` you will have `<array>` tag, add the following inside `<array>` tag.

```
<string>-vm</string>
<string>YOUR_JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib</string>
```

Replace `YOUR_JAVA_HOME` with the output of `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.*`. Then eclipse will run on that particular JVM.

For example my Info.plist has the following

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
<array>
    <string>-vm</string>
    <string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib</string>
    <string>-keyring</string>
    <string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
    <string>-showlocation</string>
</array>
```

Comment: the output of that command is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home - which just gives me the error again.

Comment: Then you have to install jdk 1.8 download it from oracle.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

Oct 14 - got the same error.

You can actually get rid of all the problems by simply installing the appropriate JDK. Make sure you install the full SDK and not the JRE. See Link below.

This worked for me - now I'm able to install Eclipse Mars.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.  My system:
OS X Yosemite
Version 10.10.5

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
```

But www.java.com/verify/ says I have Version 8!? Clearly I have a two versions that are not configured correctly.

Here is how I fixed it:
Make sure you download the Oracle version of the JDK from a .dmg file.  I 
installed Java SE JDK for Mac OS from 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Then I told java_home to use this new version:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v jdk1.8.0_111 --exec javac -version
```

Now:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    1.8.0_111, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home

... and the Eclipse install works great!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.  Had downloaded the JRE by mistake because that's what Oracle recommended.  Make sure you have the SDK.  It's about 500mb.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse mars minimum Java required is Java 7 refer the below site

[Eclipse/Installation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable System Integrity Protection and then install the newest version of Java. To disable System Integrity:

1. Restart your Mac.
2. Press "Command + R".
3. In the menu bar, find Utilities, and open Terminal.
4. Type "csrutil disable; restart".

Answer (score 0):

You can disable System Integrity Protection and then install the newest version of `Java`. To disable System Integrity:

1. Restart your `Mac`.
2. Press `Command + R`.
3. In the menu bar, find [Utilities](http://jvm.com), and open Terminal. Type
   `csrutil disable; restart`.